# Galois morphism - group acting on the variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow S$ be a finite Galois morphism, where $X$ and $S$ are non-singular and connected projective varieties over the field of complex numbers.

What does this mean? That $f$ is a finite morphism of varieties. The Galois group $G=Gal(K(X)/K(S))$ acts on $X$, and the quotient of the action is $S$. Is this correct? This has to mean that the Galois group is finite group right? Because, the extension $[K(S):K(X)]$ is a finite extension.

Is $G$ a reductive group? I see statements about taking quotient by a reductive group.

Comment: All of what you say is correct. While quotienting by reductive groups make sense sometimes, for a finite group (which is much simpler) it always makes sense.

Comment: @Mohan, I saw the following statement. Suppose we have a short exact sequence of coherent sheaves on $X$  say $0\rightarrow F'\rightarrow F\rightarrow F''\rightarrow 0$. Let the push forward  of the short exact sequence to $S=X/G$ continue to be exact. Then the functor which associates to any coherent sheaf $E$ on $S$, its subsheaf $E^G$ of $G$ invariants is also exact when $G$ is a reductive group. Is this true when $G$ is a finite group as well? (When $G$ is a finite group, the push forward sequence is exact)

Comment: @Mohan, oops, did your comment also mean that a finite group is reductive? That will answer the question in my previous comment.

Comment: Typically, for an algebraic group, reductive means the connected component of the identity is reductive. For a finite group this is obvious. (Note: Finite group schemes are slightly different, but quotients by a finite group(scheme) are easy).

Comment: @Mohan, thanks. Just a quick doubt because you said finite groups schemes are different. Does the exactness of $G$-invariants functor hold?

Comment: Essentially should follow from Hilbert 90 for most cases.