# Group Acting on Variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, projective-varieties

My question refers to some comments occured in following thread:

[Galois morphism - group acting on the variety](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313773/galois-morphism-group-acting-on-the-variety)

The setting is that we have a finite Galois morphism $f: X \to S$, where $X$ and $S$ are non-singular and connected projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$.

Galois means here that if we denote with  $G$  the automorphism group of $X$ over $S$ then the quotient $X/G$ exists and the natural morphism $X/G \to S $ is an isomorphism.

While the discussion there occured two points making me curious:

Firstly, @user52991 question if one start with exact sequence

$$0\rightarrow F'\rightarrow F\rightarrow F''\rightarrow 0$$

of coherent sheaves on $X$ and applying the pushforward $f_*$ gives an  short exact, (since $f$ finite !) sequence

$$0 \rightarrow f_*F'\rightarrow f_*F\rightarrow f_*F''\rightarrow 0$$

over $S= X/G$.

My first question is how and why does $G$ act on these pushforward sheaves explicitely? The cruical point is how does it act on local sections $f_*F(U)$? 
And second question:

If we were able to answer that the $G$-action is welldefined on the sheaves above then we can indeed deride the functor of invariants $E \to E^G$. And there ocured the question of this functor is exact.

@Mohan explained that the exactness is based on Hilbert 90 thm. Could anybody explain this argument a bit more how Hilbert 90 is inveolved in the problem?

Comment: Start with $\mathbb{C}(S) = \mathbb{C}(X)^G$ and $G$ a finite group of birational maps $X \to X$ ?

Comment: @reuns: Ah ok the $G$-action make sense on global section, but what about the local sections? Concretely an automorphism $g: X \to X$ induces the rings morphisms on local sections in following way:
 Let $U \subset X$, then  $$g_U ^{\#}:\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_X) \to \Gamma(U, g_*\mathcal{O}_X)= \Gamma(g^{-1}(U), \mathcal{O}_X)$$ 
And here occurs to me the question how $G$ can act on the local sections $\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_X)$? This action only make sense if $g^{-1}(U)$ for all $g \in G$ and $ U \subset X$, right?

Comment: @reuns: Therefore I don't know why it make sense to define $\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_X)^G$. On the other hand since $g^{-1}(X)=X$ it make sense to define the action on global sections $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$, and this induces well defined $\mathbb{C}(S) = \mathbb{C}(X)^G$, but since we expect that $X/G$ has a variety structure (especially a scheme structure) it should be possible to talk about local sections of $X/G$. What are they?

The similar problem occures when we want to transfer the action of $G$ to pushforards $f_*F$. How does this concretely look like on ***local*** sections?

Comment: Let $X =  \mathbb{A^1_C}$ and $f(x) = 1/x$ and $G = \{1,f\}$. Then $G$ is regular on $X - \{0\} \cong X'=\{(x,y),xy=1\} \subset \mathbb{A^2_C}$ and $\mathbb{C}(X)=\mathbb{C}(X-\{0\})$. On $X'$, $G$ become a group of polynomial maps and $\mathbb{C}(X')^G =\mathbb{C}(Y)$ where $Y= \{ \{ (x,y),(f(x),f(y))\},xy=1\}=\{ \{ (x,y),(y,x)\},xy=1\}\cong $ (symmetric polynomials) $\{ (x+y,xy),xy=1\} = h(W)$ where $W=\{ (x,y,u,v), u=x+y,v=xy,xy=1\})$ and $h(x,y,u,v)= (u,v)$ so $h(W) = V( (u-x-y,v-xy,xy-1) \cap \mathbb{C}[u,v])$ an affine variety. Won't the general case be similar ?