# Automorphism Group of a Variety acts on Local Sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes, projective-varieties

The motivation/background of my question arises from following thread:

[Galois morphism - group acting on the variety](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313773/galois-morphism-group-acting-on-the-variety)

The original setting is that we have a finite Galois morphism $f: X \to S$, where $X$ and $S$ are non-singular and connected projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$.

Galois means here that if we denote with  $G$  the automorphism group of $X$ over $S$ then the quotient $X/G$ exists and the natural morphism $X/G \to S $ is an isomorphism.

For futher discussion I would like to use the language of schemes to consider the topic from more general point of view by taking into account that basically a variety is a scheme $X$ over $k$ such that $X$ is
integral and the structure morphism $X \to Spec(k)$ is separated and of finite type.

While the discussion @user52991 mentioned following statement:

Let $$0 \to F′ \to F \to F′′\to 0$$ be a short exact sequence of coherent sheaves on X. Let the push forward $f_*$ of the short exact sequence to $S=X/G$ be exact (since $f$ finite this holds automatically). The aim is to consider the functor which associates to any coherent sheaf $E$ on $S$, its subsheaf $E^G$ of $G$ invariants. I don't know why it is well defined.

Here occure some understanding problems to me:

First of all: How does $G$ act on ***local*** sections of $X$? Namely, for $U \subset X$ the rings $\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_X)$?

So if we take $g \in G= Aut(X)$ then $g: X \to X$ as morphism of schemes induce ring maps

$$g_U ^{\#}:\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_X) \to \Gamma(U, g_*\mathcal{O}_X)= \Gamma(g^{-1}(U), \mathcal{O}_X)$$

And here occurs to me the core question how $G$ can act on the local sections $\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_X)$? This action only make sense if $g^{-1}(U)=U$ for all $g \in G$ and $ U \subset X$, right? Therefore I don't know why it make sense to define the invaraint subring $\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_X)^G$. On the other hand since $g^{-1}(X)=X$ it make sence to define the action on global sections $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$.

Therefore only in this special case it make sense to set $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)^G := \Gamma(X/G, \mathcal{O}_{X/G})$. But what about local sections?

Since we expect that $X/G$ has a variety structure (especially a scheme structure) it should be possible to talk about local sections of $X/G$. What are they?

If we can solve this question then the next problem would be how the $G$- action is extended the the coherent sheaves $f_*F$ as given in the exact sequence after applying $p_*$? or more generally any coherent sheaves $E$ on $S$?

Comment: Let $\{U_i\}$ be an affine $G$-invariant open cover of $X$. Then, $G$ acts on $U_i$ and thus on the regular functions on $U_i$ enabling you to define $U_i/G$. They patch up to give you $S$. The $U_i$ exists in your case, since $G$ is finite.

Comment: @Mohan: so on these invariant sets we can set $\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_X)^G := \Gamma(U/G, \mathcal{O}_{X/G})$, ok. What about the coherent sheaves $f_*F$?

Naively I would try following: 

By definition since $f_*F$ stay coherent we find locally a finite representation

$$0 \to \mathcal{O}_U^n \to \mathcal{O}_U^m \to f_*F_U \to 0$$ If we take $U$ small enough and $G$-invariant by argument above $G$ acts on local sections $\Gamma(V, \mathcal{O}_U)$ and this provides an local action on $\Gamma(V, \mathcal{O}_U^n)= \Gamma(V, \mathcal{O}_U)^n$ for $V$ small enough and invariant.

Comment: Is then $G$-action on $f_*F$ locally desribed by $G$-action on $$0 \to \mathcal{O}_U^n \to \mathcal{O}_U^m$$? Or is this consideration wrong?

Comment: If $G$ acts on $U=\mathrm{Spec}\, A$ and $M$ is a module over $A$, then $G$ acts on $M$ naturally(not as $A$-module homomorphism). Thus, $G$ acts on $M$ as $A^G$-module.

Comment: @Mohan: I'm not sure how this action on $A$ can be extended to a $A$-module $M$. Let $g \in G$. How does it act on $M$? I don't see it. The naive approach via $a * m \mapsto a^g * m$ is obviously not well defined.

Comment: I have seen many question of yours about more or less the same content. I saw several answers and comments (including some of mine) saying that in general there is no action of $G$ on $f_*\mathcal{F}$. So I guess there is still something missing in your hypotheses. If you are working on an article, maybe you can link it. If this is only the thread mentioned at the beginning of the post, I would recommend to not take it for absolute truth. This is only an SE post and maybe many details were implicit or came from previous post/discussions.

Comment: The usual definition of an action of $G$ on a scheme endowed with an action of $G$, is the data for all $g\in G$ of a map $\phi_g:\mathcal{F}\to g_*\mathcal{F}$, such that for the neutral element $e\in G$, we have $\phi_e:\mathcal{F}\to e_*\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{F}$ is the identity, and $\phi_{gh}:\mathcal{F}\to g_*h_*\mathcal{F}$ is the same as the composite $(g_*\phi_h)\circ \phi_g:\mathcal{F}\to g_*\mathcal{F}\to g_*h_*\mathcal{F}$. We say that these datas is an action of $G$ compatible with the one on $X$.

Comment: With this definition, if $\mathcal{G}$ is any module on $X/G$, then its pullback on $X$ is endowed with a $\mathcal{G}$ action compatible with the one on $X$. Conversely, if $\mathcal{F}$ is any module on $X$ endowed with a $G$ action compatible with that of $X$ (as above), then its pushforward on $X/G$ is a module with a usual $G$-action.

Comment: Look at an example : if $L/K$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $G$ and $X=\operatorname{Spec L}$, then a $\mathcal{O}_X$-module is a $L$-vector space $V$. If we see $V$ as a $K$-vector space, it does not come necessarily with a $G$ action. We do not want an action of $G$ on $V$ neither. Instead, we want an action such that $g(\lambda v)=g(\lambda)g(v)$. If you think about it, this is exactly the kind of data encoded in the maps $\phi_g$ and the condition that $\phi_{gh}=(g_*\phi_h)\circ\phi_g$.

Comment: @Roland: I'm not sure why the condition $\phi_{gh}=(g_*\phi_h)\circ\phi_g$ coinsides exactly with the condition $g(\lambda v)=g(\lambda)g(v)$ (i e the property of a group action on modules) in affine case in your example where $X= Spec(L)$, $V$ $L$-vector space and $G$ Galois group. 
Here $\phi_g$ corresponds to the the multiplication map $V \to V, l \mapsto g \cdot l$ on the module side, right?

Comment: $\phi_g$ is a map $V\to V$. It is not given for free, it is a structure you have to put. Thus I can't tell you what it is. As I said, $V$ does not come with a $G$ action.

Comment: @Roland: Yes, but $V$ obtains action described by the family of $\phi_g$ as $L$-module? The point that isn't clear to me is what is the affine (so on $L$-module side) pendant for the condition $\phi_{gh}=(g_*\phi_h)\circ\phi_g$? Or in other words how does it "translates" in affine case?

Comment: @Roland: Another point: How does the characterisation of a $G$ action as you gave above correlates with the characterisation in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_sheaf? Is it literally the same or is wiki's description some kind of descent data for your characterisation, ie there exist for (nice enough) schemes a category equivalence between the the schemes with $G$ action data as you described above and the pulled back "descent data" as explained by wiki?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88554/discussion-between-roland-and-karlpeter).