# $G$-Action on a Ring extends to a Module

Tags: commutative-algebra, group-actions

Let $A$ be ring endowed with $G$-action by a group. Take any arbitrary $A$-module $M$.

Is there a canonical way to extend the $G$-action to $M$? I'm not sure how to avoid the problem with well definess if I try to settle the action in naive way via $am \mapsto a^g m$.

The background of my question is [Automorphism Group of a Variety acts on Local Sections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3071478/automorphism-group-of-a-variety-acts-on-local-sections)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not.  For example, in the case where $M$ is $A$ itself, in order for the action of $G$ on $M$ to deserve the name "canonical", it would need to commute with any automorphism of $M$ as a module.  Concretely, that means that every unit of $A$ would have to be fixed by the action of $G$, which certainly is not true in general.

Comment: This is a simple and intuitive answer.

Comment: Yes, this is the point. Do you maybe have an idea which $G$-action on an $A$-module @Mohan mean in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3071478/automorphism-group-of-a-variety-acts-on-local-sections?noredirect=1&lq=1 ?

Comment: I think he was confused.